# Происхождение слова "пельмени"

Tags: этимология

Пельмени — блюдо русской кухни (хотя встречаются и в других кухнях мира), но откуда взялось название?

Comment: Вопрос уже был на форуме, см. [пельмень](http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/4086/%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C)

Comment: Эх, не видел я. но сейчас, думаю, не стоит уже закрывать...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из финно-угорских, скорее всего из языка коми, где значит "хлебные уши", по другой версии - "медвежьи уши".

Answer (score 1):

По Фасмеру: "Заимств. из коми, удм. реl᾽ńаń от коми, удм. реl᾽ "ухо", ńań "хлеб", из-за формы, которую имеют эти изделия".